# Laravel - Rest Api give Cache Access Denied Error

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am new in Laravel 5.4.

I am developing Rest Api for my application in Laravel.

But issue is that when I post or get from Laravel API through Postman it is giving below error.

```
ERROR

Cache Access Denied.
```